# Confuse about ecto relationship

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have following schemas:

```
  schema "countries" do

    belongs_to :lang, LanguageCode, foreign_key: :code
    field :text, :string

    timestamps

  end

  schema "languages_code" do

    has_one :code, Country, foreign_key: :lang
    field :text, :string

    timestamps
  end
```

My question is, when I am going to create the third table that should belongs to LanguageCode too:

```
schema "table3" do

  belongs_to :coun, CountryCode, foreign_key: :alpha2
  field :text, :string

  timestamps

end
```

how do I have to modify the languages_code schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, what your asking is how to represent the `belongs_to` relationship on the LanguagesCode model?

If so then depending on whether or not a Language code can have one or more `table3` rows belonging to it, you would do:

```
 schema "languages_code" do

    has_one :code, Country, foreign_key: :lang

    #For has_one
    has_one :code, Table3ModuleName, foreign_key: :alpha2

    #For has_many
    has_many :code, Table3ModuleName, foreign_key: :alpha2 

    field :text, :string

    timestamps
  end
```

You would of course replace, `Table3ModuleName` with the actual name of the module containing the `table3` table schema definition.

Comment: What make be confuse is, how I have to design the schema. The concept is sometimes so weird. How to understand ecto better?

Comment: @zero_coding that really isn't an ecto question, that's more of a database design question if I'm understanding you correctly.

I'd be happy to give you more help in regards to designing the database but I need to know more about the domain and what you are trying to achieve. Maybe edit your original post to include that